# CSS Parallax (Firefox) works on my website, but not another

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to figure out why my parallax effect doesn't appear to work on another website but it does on my own.

General HTML structure of the website it works on:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parallax">
      <header class="parallax__group">
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back darken"></div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base flex alignvcenter">
          <p>Content here</p>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Link to website](http://www.martynleeball.com/mps)

And this is the general HTML structure of the other website, can't modify any of this apart from between the comments:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AutoDealer">
      <div id="main-wrap" class="parallax">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="main twelvecol">

            <!-- Editable -->
            <div>
              <div class="row-block finance parallax__group">
                <div class="parallax__layer--back parallax__layer"></div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="parallax__layer--base parallax__layer">
                      <p>This is all of the top level content</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Editable -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Link to website](http://devsite104.clickserver.co.uk/)

Again, this issue is on Firefox (Edge too but probably same issue). If you follow the links and take a look for yourself and inspect the code.

Not too sure what's causing the issue, as far as I can tell the styles are the same, I have tried copying the working styles to the none working one but still doesn't solve the issue, maybe an HTML issue?

CSS Styles:

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    preserve-origin-x: 100%;
    &--ie { display: block; }
    &__group {
      position: relative;
      // transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    &__layer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      &--base {
        transform: translateZ(0);
        position: relative;
        float: left;
      }
      &--back {
        transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
        height: 100vh;
      }
      &--middle {
        transform: translateZ(-1.6px) scale(2.6);
        p {
          font-size: 20vw;
          color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does the css get compiled well on the other site?

Comment: Whoops forgot it was compiled. They are both using the same compiler, well, ive disabled it on the martynleeball.com one.